# What are the differences between all print functions in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm pretty new to C. What are the differences between printf, vprintf, vfprintf, vsprintf, and vsnprintf?

Comment: Some [useful documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).

Comment: If you ask this question, it means that you do not need any `v` functions.

Comment: There is no "comparison table" because they are not really comparable - they each do different things. The `v` prefix functions take a `va_list` argument and can be used to implement formatted output variadic functions _like_ `printf()`.  The `s` prefix indicates it outputs to a string buffer rather than `stdout`. The `f` prefix indicates output to a `FILE*`.  The `n` prefix indicates the function takes a buffer length argument to prevent buffer overrun.  You have omitted `fprintf()`, `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` which are the more likely variants you will encounter.

Comment: Note that it is possible an likely that `printf()` is implemented by `fprintf()` (since `stdout` is a `FILE*` stream), and in turn `fprintf()` might be implemented by `vfprintf()`.  Unless you are implementing your own `printf()`-like variadic functions the `v` prefix variants are not useful to you.

Comment: I've removed the part where I've asked for documents. I think this question should get opened again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Printf is "print formatted", it takes a format string and a series of format arguments in the form of varargs, applies the formatting and writes the output to standard output.

The "f" variants write output to a file instead of standard output.

The "s" variants write to a character array instead of standard output. Unfortunately the basic sprintf function has no overflow protection making it risky to use unless you have carefully calculated the maximum possible size (and not made any unwarranted assumptions in said calculation).  snprintf adds a size limit.

The "v" variants take a va_list rather than taking varargs directly. They are usefull when writing a wrapper function that takes varargs from the user and passes them on to printf.